# Multiple condition is not executed in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want the marks should get matched with required grade criteria. I tried `xsl:choose` to check the marks condition, but it was not checking the when condition it always executes otherwise condition. Can anyone share the solution?

XML:

```xml
{
<marklist>
    <student>
        <reg_no>100</reg_no>
        <name>aaa</name>
        <marks>
            <CD>55</CD>
            <AI>44</AI>
        </marks>
    </student>
    <student>
        <reg_no>101</reg_no>
        <name>bbb</name>
        <marks>
            <CD>65</CD>
            <AI>46</AI>
        </marks>
    </student>
</marklist>
}
```

Required XML format:

```xml
{
<marklist>
    <student>
        <reg_no>100</reg_no>
        <name>aaa</name>
        <grade>
            <CD>D</CD>
            <AI>E</AI>
        </grade>
    </student>
    <student>
        <reg_no>101</reg_no>
        <name>bbb</name>
        <grade>
            <CD>C</CD>
            <AI>E</AI>
        </grade>
    </student>
</marklist>
}
```

Comment: Very difficult to answer without seeing your XSLT.

Comment: If you want us to tell you what is wrong with your code, well be happy to do so, but you need to show us your code. (Don't be nervous of showing your code. We'll be critical, but we would be equally critical if you were a world expert. One thing that makes people into world experts is that they have learnt to welcome criticism.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CD">
        <CD>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 60 and . &gt; 50">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'D'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 70 and . &gt; 60">
                <xsl:value-of select="'C'"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </CD>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AI">
        <AI>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 60 and . &gt; 50">
                <xsl:value-of select="'D'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 70 and . &gt; 60">
                <xsl:value-of select="'C'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". &lt; 50 and . &gt; 30">
                <xsl:value-of select="'E'"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        </AI>
    </xsl:template>

You may check value of CD and AI and apply Grade according to that
```